# state not updating immediately - updating only on second time - NEXT.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a login form with name, email and password. I have done validation for the same. My requirement is, the form should be submitted only after validation success. Check below code,

```
const [error, setError] = useState(false);
const [errorEmail, setEmailError] = useState(false);
const [errorMsg, setMsgState] = useState({
    name : "",
    email : "",
    password : ""
});
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (name.trim() === '') {
        setError(true);
        setMsgState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            name: '* Name required'
        }))
    }

    if (email.trim() === '') {
        setError(true);
        setMsgState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            email: '* Email required'
        }))
    }

    if (password.trim() === '') {
        setError(true);
        setMsgState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            password: '* Password required'
        }))
    }

    if (email.trim() !== '') {
        if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(email)) {
            setEmailError(true);
            setMsgState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                email: '* Enter valid email'
            }))
        }
        else
            setEmailError(false);
    }

    if (!error && !errorEmail) {
        const user = { name, email, password };

        dispatch(authenticate(user));
    }
};
```

In the above code, when user click on submit button first time, validation messages is showing and also the form is submitting. On the second time form is not submitting, just showing the validation messages only. `State is not updating immediately`. How to alter my code to acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add error checking in useEffect hook,

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if (!error && !errorEmail) {
    const user = { name, email, password };
    dispatch(authenticate(user));
    }
},[error,errorEmail])
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use `@hapi/joi` input validation package it is most popular package. if you want to keep this, you can do one thing, instead of set state each errors, just make one new function and validate your input in that function, the validateInput function will returns either error message or success message if all the input is validated. 

`const [user, setUser ] = useState({name:"", email:"", password:"" })` make one state only. then in a handle submit method, do `let res = validateInput(user)`
`if res === "success" dispatch...`
`else setErrorMessage(response)`